# JSF form - submit > focus on selected input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I have this theoretical situation:

- one view with one form [`ID: frm`]
- three components (e.g. `h:inputText`) [`ID: inp1, inp2, inp3`]
- three submit buttons [`ID: btn1, btn2, btn3`]

When I submit the form using `btn1`, I need to focus to `inp1` (analogical `btn2` to `inp2`, `btn3` to `inp3`)

I'm able to use `javaScript` function like `onclick="document.getElementById('frm:inp1').focus();"` (it works)

Problem is, that submit button causes recreating of view and after that, javaScript setting is forgotten and component is not selected..

So how do I select a component which remains selected even after the view redraws?

Comment: So your aim is to prevent the view from reconstructing or getting javascript to remember the setting after the view is recreated? Also, what is the "view" are you working in asp.net MVC?

Comment: @MrJD: OP is using JSF which is a component based MVC framework from Java EE. Hover the [jsf] tag below question and click the *info* link.

Comment: I'm working with Java EE, I think I need javaScript to rememeber it after view is recreated..

Comment: would you be better off using submit function to call some ajax that then re-renders the page as necessary client side? (edit:) oh and forgive my lack of knowledge in this framework but is it possible to select the element in the code that is called when you submit?

Comment: i'm not sure what do you think, all I know is, that recreate of view is the last last step of JSF lifecycle.. I'm able to use ajax for some kind of stuff but recreate page using AJAX? no.. I can choose the component on load of view using JavaScript (`window.onload = function;`) and perhaps is it also possible using some filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include a script in your page which will update the focus after page is rendered. Update information about focused input on the server in action listeners. The script can look look like this with jquery:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() { document.getElementById('frm:#{focusInfo.componentId}').focus(); })
</script>
```

It is assuming you have set componentId property in focusInfo bean in action/actionListener executed on server upon button click. FocusInfo contains componentId with getter and setter and possibly methods switching componentId and registered as actionListeners with your buttons.

Comment: One small thing, when I place it to the js file, it doesn't work, because `#{focusInfo.componentId}` couldn't be resolved.. is it also possible to define backing beans in js files?

Comment: I haven't tried that. You would either have to map .js to faces servlet or change this particular file extension to .xhtml. Both choices seem a little awkward, I usually just live with <script> tags in my xhtml. Just keeping them as one-liners and extracting more complex logic into functions kept in js files.

Comment: I'll do it as you advise me. It's very ample solution, thank you again!

Answer (score -1):

Use the PrimeFaces component:

```
<!-- Focus on first field, or first field with error -->
<p:focus context="feesboek"/>
```

Use this in combination with a focus component and you will rock!

```
<!-- Default button when pressing enter -->
<p:defaultCommand target="submit"/>
```